# Unity 3D couldn't connect to host. localhost with ip

Tags: unity-game-engine, laravel-5

I am trying to HTTP POST to Laravel 5 using Unity.
The code is:

```js
 public void postToDB()
    {
        Debug.Log("in1");

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("fb_id", "123123123");
   
        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost:777/new_fb_user",form);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www),form);
    }
    private IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
    {
        Debug.Log("in2");
        yield return www;

        // check for errors
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
        }
    }
```

When I try to use the `postToDB` method, I get this error:

```
WWW Error: couldn't connect to host UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<WaitForRequest>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/GameManger.cs:41)
```

I am using Wamp and I added a `crossdomain.xml` file.

If I change `http://localhost:777/new_fb_user` to any domain like Facebook or Google, it connects to that host. The POST command works: I tested it using Postman. So, I think the error is coming from Unity.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the sample code, StartCoroutine should be called like this: StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www)) or StartCoroutine("WaitForRequest",www). That being said I don't think this is gonna fix your issue.

Comment: Do you get the `in2` log? Is your localhost connectable by other means, for example what happens if you put your request into a web browser or curl?

Comment: It connected fine and i get response >using any browser or Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it , the problem that i was running the laravel project internally 
using the normal 
php artisan serve 
which was as creating private internal server 
i fix it using Xampp 
-coping the laravel project to htdocs folder in Xampp directory 
-running Xampp serve

it worked perfectly
Thanks for the help every one